# I need a word for the time just before some other moment. Like upon, only in reverse

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I wrote a program that must add to some log entry (of some event) a note if event happened just before some other major event or along with it. And i cannot select a good word for this.

This word marks entries for closed browser windows if they closed just before (several seconds) or along with the complete browser close. But it must be a word or a short phrase.

Example:

> Window X closed ***_*__*_*__** Chrome Exit
>       Window Y closed ***_*__*_*__** Chrome Exit
>       Window Z closed ***_*__*_*__** Chrome Exit

I cannot use any of *on/during/upon/before/ahead/along/by the time/onward/onwards/preceding/ahead/along/near/fore* as the window might be closed just before, simultaneously with Chrome exit.

*Upon* looks very good, but as I understand it is for the moment just after the major event. *Before* cannot be used as it includes too long a timeframe. *On* feels for me like it does not include the time just before the exit.

I need a word or phrase for "just before or in time of".

Comment: How about simply:  *Window X closed* **prior to** *Chrome exit* and *Window X closed* **at** *Chrome exit*.  If Window X closed independent of Chrome exit, then the event would only be *Window X closed* and would not mention Chrome at all.

Comment: I think technical documentation needs more use of the term *on the cusp of*.

Comment: The problem is that I only need log entries for windows closed just before or at the moment of exit, and actually cannot distinguish them - so log entry must not mislead. And there must not be any other closed windows in a log. But "at" looks very well actually... i feels it's include some short timeframe, not exact point in time - am i am right? (not a native, sorry)

Comment: well, it is not an documentation actually, for documention it is maybe ok to say "on the cusp of", but this is actually a user interface, too pretentious for everyday use, ...

Comment: If you can't distinguish whether a windows closed prior to or simultaneously with Chrome's exit, then just say the window closed *around the time* of Chrome exit.  Out of curiosity how close to Chrome's exit must it be to report it?  If it closed 10 mins prior would you report it?  How about 10 secs?  How about 10 ms?

Comment: "prior to" maybe also looks good... thanks for the tip.

Comment: "around the time" of Chrome exit looks perfect, but too long... 
can "upon" be used in this context? or it is really only for a moment after?

Comment: /// Out of curiosity how close to Chrome's exit must it be to report it?  /// - must report it only if it is closed no further than 2-3 seconds before exit.

Comment: how about *near*?

Comment: neer - perfect!!, only feels a little awkward to use it with moments of time, but.... this is seems the best - thank you very much : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A marginal rephrasing may be necessary or at least desirable to make the log entry clearer.

> Window X closed **followed by** Chrome Exit

***Followed by*** gives the sense of 'succeeding' and also of immediacy; i.e., 'Chrome Exit' occurs immediately after 'Window X closed'.

Reversing the semantics this way rather than using an antonym can solve it. Stating the time of occurrence of an event in terms of another event that has not yet taken place ("*before*") can result in non-linearity. Instead, the use of *followed by* keeps the events independent and linear:

Window X closed (in absolute terms with no reference in time)
then immediately:
Chrome Exit  (happened in absolute terms with no direct reference in time)

---

[EDIT-1]
Considering various possibilities:

- Window Closure prior to and due to Chrome Exit
- Window Closure following and due to Chrome Exit
- Window Closure for reasons unknown or not relevant, but during Chrome Exit

the one thing that can be said with certainty is that the two events

- "A certain Window has closed"
- "Chrome Exit"

are approximately concurrent.

As such, one has to use *with* instead of *followed by* in referring to the course of events. Using *with* will serve to indicate the **approximately concurrency** without expressly stating the **order of the events**. Consider:

> Window X closed **with** Chrome Exit

Comment: The problem is, the window is closed most of the time BECAUSE of Chrome exit. And some times, rarely, really just before. I cannot distinguish this 2 cases so i must present both of them. But the log entry must clearly indicate for user why it is there - it is not interested actually in any Windows close at all. Even more, it is strange to find them in this concrete log - so to give clues why this log entries is there in a first place (because they appear on Chrome exit) is the most important aim. 
I need to show this somewhat special closed windows, and i must justify to user why i do this.

Comment: I cannot say "closed because of Chrome exit". As i really don't know for sure.

Comment: I think that this might be considered a spam, or something like this. Yet anyway nobody already visit to this question, so, just if somebody really interested. There is the extension for Chrome [TabsOutliner](http://tabsoutliner.com) - might be actually useful for anybody, so worth to look - it gives editable overview of all Chrome Tabs and Windows. It has problems with windows closed just before the Chrome exit. Users, for "no reason" : ) expect them to stay in a list. Despite the fact that if window is closed normally it will gone.

Comment: So i must justify and give clues (by title) why i leave them in a list, yet not any other windows.

Comment: Reread again you answer and start to think that at list it is the best so far... yet not ideal...